# PHP class to read emails with attachments through IMAP

Tags: php, email, imap, attachment

I am looking for PHP class, that helps me read emails and their attachments.

I tried to write it on my own with IMAP class in PHP, but emails exists in many, many formats. And it is complicated to include all of them to get some reasonable text output.

It should look something like this:

```
$mailbox = Mailbox("{localhost:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "user_id", "password");
$unreadMessages = $mailbox->unreadMessages(); // just ids
$message = $mailbox->getMessage(5); // headers and body in plain text, ids of attachments
$message->saveAttachment(1, '/path/to/attachments/folder');
$message->seen();
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: @DaveRandom: if only that were true. Many seem to deviate from the standards.

Comment: The Mailbox class from flourish is sometimes recommended http://flourishlib.com/docs/fMailbox - Albeit I'm not sure about how mail structuring affect attachment extraction capabilities. Do you mean MIME vs Outlook attachments?

Comment: @Evert Good point - I suppose that should have read "Email messages **should** exist in *one* format..."

Comment: have you tried http://php.net/imap

Comment: @DaveRandom: Yes, emails should exists in one format. But in real world, you'll recieve email in many forms. And it isn't easy to manage them all and convert them to nice plain text output. I don't want to study how MIME works. I asked, if there is some useful class for this with simple API. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

I use `Mail` component from [Apache Zeta Components](http://incubator.apache.org/zetacomponents/). It's really easy to use. I had a working prototype in under one hour.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Zend_Mail` - it has lots of options, you will probably find everything you need. Maybe not as simple as your code above, but as you said yourself, there are a lot of options.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html